# How to calculate the difference in example below

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to calculate difference between the "Total Marks" in a question, and the text inputs for each answer in a question. Also if a question has only one answer, then it should display the text input as a readonly and display the same value as the number under the "Total Mark" for that question in that text input.

Below is a screenshot which shows the table and the written problem I have with both scenarios:

[image: Screenshot of table and information on problems]

Below is the current jquery variable which should be doing the calculation and display the readonly textbox when necessary. But at the moment it is not working. Also at the moment I have display the number for total marks to be fixed as "5" when doing the calculations, well this is incorrect as that it should be the number for within each row, so I believe the variable `$sessionMarks` that should be the number, not 5.

```
$(function(){             
var questions = $('#markstbl td[class*="_ans"]').length-1;

//disable single entry
for (var i=0;i<=questions;i++){   
if($("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").length ==1){
$("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").attr("disabled","disabled")
}                    
}

//find each question set and add listeners
for (var i=0;i<=questions;i++){                                     
$('input[class*="q'+i+'"]').keyup(function(){
var cl = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]
var questionno = cl.substring(cl.indexOf('q')+1,cl.indexOf('_'))
var t=0;
$("[class*=q"+questionno+"_mark]").each(function(){
var num = (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())))?0:parseInt($(this).val());
t+=parseInt(num);                             
})   
var fixedno = 5;
$(".q"+questionno+"_ans").text((t>fixedno)?fixedno:t);
})
}
})
```

Below is the code for the table, from the query it outputs the details of each question from the database and then it displays it in a table:

```
<?php

$assessment = $_SESSION['id'] . $sessionConcat;

include('connect.php');

   $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
   FROM Session s 
   INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
   JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
   WHERE s.SessionName = ?
   ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
   ";

   // prepare query
   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
   // You only need to call bind_param once
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
   // execute query
   $stmt->execute(); 


       // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
   $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
      } 

?>  

....

<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
$previous_question_id = null;
$rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
$output = "";
$questionid = 0; //whole question
$questionno = 0; //part of question
foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key => $question) {
if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]){
$questionno=0;
}

// removed logic, not necessary to set empty strings if you're skipping them
$output.= '<tr class="questiontd">' . PHP_EOL;
if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
$output.= '<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="' . $rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]) . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
$output.= '<td class="questioncontenttd q{$questionno++}_mark{$questionid}" rowspan="' . $rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($question) . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}

$output.= '<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">';
$output.= $searchAnswer[$key];
$output.= '</td>';
$output.= '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" /></td>' . PHP_EOL;

if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
$output.= '<td class="noofmarkstd  q{$questionid++}_ans" q_group="1" rowspan="' . $rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]) . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}

// moved this to the end
if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
$previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
}
}
echo $output;
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**Update:**

In the sample HTML which is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWTQk/18/), I can get it to work (except I want the calculation to be total marks minus number entered in text input, not what it is doing now which is when I enter a number in text input it performs an addition from 0 to whatever number entered in text input), but when I tried to edit the code above to do the same thing, then it doesn't work, nothing happens.

The sample html is below:

```
<form id="Marks" action="/u0867587/Mobile_app/individualmarks.php" method="post">

<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="3">1</td>
<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="3">Name three features in a ROM</td>
<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">A</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q0_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q0_ans"  q_group="1" rowspan="3">5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">B</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q0_mark_1" q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">D</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q0_mark_2" q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="1">2</td>
<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="1">Here is a single answer</td>
<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">True</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0" q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q1_ans" q_group="1" rowspan="1">5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Below is what the database tables looks like, (this will follow the same data as the ones in the screenshot)

**Session Table:** (Where the exam details is stored)

```
SessionId  SessionName
1          AAA
```

**Question Table:** (Where questions for each exams are stored)

```
SessionId   QuestionId       QuestionContent                Total Marks
1                 1          Name three features in a ROM        5 
1                 2          Here is a single answer             5
```

**Answer Table:** (Stores answers for each question in each exam)

```
AnswerId(auto)  SessionId QuestionId  Answer
1               1         1           A
2               1         1           B
3               1         1           D
4               1         2           True
```

**Individual_Answer Table:** (Stores each individual mark for each individual answer)

```
AnswerId   AnswerMarks
1          2
2          2
3          1
4          5
```

Comment: please provide and example HTML for the tables because we do not have db to make the html.

Comment: I have updated question to include sample html. Please read the update carefully so you know what is happening and what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good practice to get and put values from html elements using html() which somehow belong to calculation or integers values, Therefore always use hidden fields for this type of problems, like I have included two hidden fields one for original value and one for the final value and at the end you can get the total marks values easily from the hidden field.

The code is updated for dynamic data. Use your own code for queries, mine is a rough code.

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {           
                var questions = $('#markstbl td[class*="_ans"]').length;

                //disable single entry
                for (var i=1;i<=questions;i++){   
                    if($("[class*=q"+i+"_marks]").length ==1){
                        var t_marks = $("[class*=q"+i+"_ans]").html();
                        alert(t_marks);
                        $("[class*=q"+i+"_marks]").val(t_marks).attr("disabled","disabled");
                        //$("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").attr("disabled","disabled");
                    }                    
                }

                //find each question set and add listeners
                for (var i=0;i<=questions;i++){                                     
                    $('input[class*="q'+i+'"]').keyup(function(){
                        var cl = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]
                        var questionno = cl.substring(cl.indexOf('q')+1,cl.indexOf('_'));
                        var tot_marks = $(".q"+questionno+"_ans_org").val();

                        var ans_t=0;
                        $("[class*=q"+questionno+"_marks]").each(function(){
                            var num = (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())))?0:parseInt($(this).val());
                            ans_t+=parseInt(num);                             
                        });
                        ans_t=tot_marks-ans_t;                             

                        var ans = (parseInt(ans_t)<0)?tot_marks:ans_t;
                        $(".q"+questionno+"_ans").val(ans);
                        $(".q"+questionno+"_ans_text").html(ans);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<form id="Marks" action="/u0867587/Mobile_app/individualmarks.php" method="post">
    <?php
    $ident = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysqli_select_db($ident,'testdata');

    $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
    FROM session s 
    INNER JOIN question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
    JOIN answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
    ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
    ";

    $res = mysqli_query($ident,$query);
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        $searchQuestionId[] = $row['QuestionId'];
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $row['QuestionContent'];
        $searchAnswer[] = $row['Answer'];
        $searchMarks[] = $row['QuestionMarks'];

    } 

?>  


<form id="Marks" action="/u0867587/Mobile_app/individualmarks.php" method="post">

<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
$output = '';
$rowCount = 1;
$newQuest_id = true;

foreach($searchQuestionId as $key=>$questionId){

    if($newQuest_id == true){

        $output.= '<tr class="questiontd">';
        $output.= '<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="'.$row_span[$questionId].'">'.$questionId.' <input type="hidden" name="q'.$questionId.'_ans_org" class="q'.$questionId.'_ans_org" value="'.$searchMarks[$key].'"><input type="hidden" name="q'.$questionId.'_ans" class="q'.$questionId.'_ans" value="'.$searchMarks[$key].'"></td>';
        $output.= '<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="'.$row_span[$questionId].'">'.$searchQuestionContent[$key].' </td>';
    }

    $output.= '<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">'.$searchAnswer[$key].'</td>';
    $output.= '<td class="answermarkstd">';
    $output.= '<input class="individualMarks q'.$questionId.'_marks"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />';
    $output.= '</td>';


    if($newQuest_id == true){
        $output.= '<td class="noofmarkstd q'.$questionId.'_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="'.$row_span[$questionId].'">'.$searchMarks[$key].'</td>';
        $newQuest_id = false;
    }
    $output.= '</tr>';

    if($row_span[$questionId] == $rowCount){
        $newQuest_id = true;
    }

    $rowCount++;
}

echo $output;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Tariq, The problem I am having is that yes, it is working in the sample html, but how can I get it working in the main code (The code where it shows the php echoing the results from the query into a html table). That is the issue I am having. Your jquery function does work but only for the sample html (Btw When calculating total marks, it should be the total marks counting down e.g. If total marks for a question is `7` (total marks isn't always 5), and there are two text input for that question with values `2` and `3`, then `7` minus `2` minus `3` will mean Total Marks will equal `2`.

Comment: the only issues I am having is that in the sample HTML you have put this in these hidden inputs `<input type="hidden" name="q0_ans_org" class="q0_ans_org" value="7"><input type="hidden" name="q0_ans" class="q0_ans" value="7">` for question 1, `<input type="hidden" name="q1_ans_org" class="q1_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q1_ans" class="q1_ans" value="5">` for question 2. My question is that how is the hidden input should be correctly written in the dynamic html data, so it knows how to correct name each hidden input per question number?

Comment: Also how do you write and change each class in dynamic HTML table for each text input as that in the sample HTML for question 1, for each text input in that question you have these three classes `individualMarks q0_mark_0`, `individualMarks q0_mark_1`, `individualMarks q0_mark_2`. Then for question 2 in the sample html, you manage to change the class to `individualMarks q1_mark_0`. Same for question 3 you change it to `individualMarks q2_mark_0`, `individualMarks q2_mark_1`and `individualMarks q2_mark_2`. I want to know to include this in the dynamic html. Do you understand?

Comment: Its is very difficult to understand the logic from the PHP you have provided because I don't know how the db is designed but as for as I understand it, don't use 
$questionid = 0; //whole question or 
$questionno = 0; //part of question for naming the classes but use the exact ID's from database. For hidden fields you can easily use the $searchQuestionId[$key], I think from database. And for the question parts, It should also have the ID's from the db, if not you can initiate a variable and then increment it for the next loop for the same question but for the next question part.

Comment: if you don't mind can you show me an update on how you would change the class for naming classes and for hidden inputs? at mean time I will include an edit showing the database design in my question which will match with the data in the screenshot